# IP to URL to Address

Tags: java, ip, ip-address, hostname

I want:
 if Input: `<IP-Address>` -> Output (EXACT!!!): `www.example.com`

Problem: If I have just one of IP-addresses (51.254.201.70) of a web site and want to find out which web-site it is, I get only like this: 70.ip-51-254-201.eu. I want to get exact www.webmoney.ru

What I've find out:

```
package PACK;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class IPtoHost4 {

  // Input:www.webmoney.com -> Output: All IP-Adresses of this Page
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {


        for (InetAddress addr : InetAddress.getAllByName("www.webmoney.ru")) {

            System.out.println(addr.getHostAddress() + " : " + getHost(addr));
        }

    // Output:
    // 5.199.142.158 : www.webmoney.ru
    // 51.254.201.70 : www.webmoney.ru
    // 62.210.115.140 : www.webmoney.ru
    // 88.99.82.144 : www.webmoney.ru

    // Input:All-IPs -> Output: hostnames
    String[] ips = { "5.199.142.158", "51.254.201.70", "62.210.115.140", "88.99.82.144" };
    for (String i : ips) {
        InetAddress ip = null;
        ip = InetAddress.getByName(i);
        System.out.println(getHost(ip));
    }
    //  Output:
    // z158.zebra.servdiscount-customer.com
    // 70.ip-51-254-201.eu
    // 62-210-115-140.rev.poneytelecom.eu
   // static.144.82.99.88.clients.your-server.de

}

static String getHost(InetAddress ip) {
    String hostName = "";
    hostName = ip.getHostName();

    return hostName;

}
```

}

Comment: Those domains you get are probably the correct ones for the ips. You might assume that the domain you're querying is redirecting you. Besides that "webmoney" and ".ru" seem fishy anyways so be careful.

Comment: There can be multiple domain names ([virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting)) on one IP address.

Comment: Hi. I have just IP-Adresses from Wireshark. And I want found out just realy HTML-Websites (DNS-Server, and Domains are not interesting for me) which are visited by my users from my server.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution how I would to find out a websites which are send HTML Code 301/302 for redirecting. But if I get **HTML Code 200** i can identify just a **host name**. I would like to identify full name of Website.

See example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String ip = "78.129.242.2";
    URL myURL = new URL("http://" + ip);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    con.connect();

    // HTML-Code from a website
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);

    // HTTP 200 OK
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        InetAddress addr = null;
        addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        String host = addr.getHostName();
        System.out.println(host);
    }

    // HTTP 301 oder 302 redirect
    else if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
        String location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
        System.out.println(location);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Bad Web Site" + " ResponceCode: " + responseCode);
    }
}
```